# preserve .txt formatting when changing to .html

Tags: html

I have a .txt file that has certain formatting. It's not too complicated:

```
Text heading
----

Point 1

Point 2

Result:
---
```

This file goes onto the server and gets displayed to a user. But when it goes there, it automatically changes the filetype to html(when originally it was just .txt) and the formatting is all gone. It becomes like

```
Text Heading ---- Point 1 Point 2 Result: -----
```

It basically gets encapsulated in a `<p></p>` 
Is there a way to preserve the basic formatting, or do I have to manually enclose it within tags to get the formatting right

Comment: one `<pre>` around all your content would be enough for basic formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either wrap your content in a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag or use some css to [preserve whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```
p {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
}
```